# Error while loading a BPF program that copies a buffer to the BPF stack

Tags: c, bpf, ebpf

I am trying to load a BPF program that simply copies the `buf` parameter of [tty_write](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v3.3/source/drivers/tty/tty_io.c#L1134) to the BPF stack. My program is as follows:

```
#define BUFSIZE 256

SEC("kprobe/tty_write")
int kprobe__tty_write(struct pt_regs *ctx, struct file *file, const char __user *buf, size_t count)
{
  char buffer[BUFSIZE];
  bpf_probe_read(buffer, BUFSIZE, (void *)buf);

  return 0;
}
```

Note that I am using [bpf_helpers.h](https://github.com/weaveworks/tcptracer-bpf/blob/master/bpf_helpers.h) from [tcptracer-bpf](https://github.com/weaveworks/tcptracer-bpf) to define the `SEC` macro. In my real program I would actually use `buffer` for something, but I have not shown that part here. When I try to load the program (from an ELF file using [gobpf](https://github.com/iovisor/gobpf)) I get the following error:

```
error while loading "kprobe/tty_write" (permission denied):
0: (bf) r1 = r10
1: (07) r1 += -256
2: (b7) r2 = 256
3: (85) call bpf_probe_read#4
R3 !read_ok
```

Why is this? My program has been adapted from [ttysnoop.py](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/tools/ttysnoop.py) so I know it is possible to do what I'm trying to do. The full disassembly of my program is as follows:

```
Disassembly of section kprobe/tty_write:
kprobe__tty_write:
       0:   bf a1 00 00 00 00 00 00     r1 = r10
       1:   07 01 00 00 00 ff ff ff     r1 += -256
       2:   b7 02 00 00 00 01 00 00     r2 = 256
       3:   85 00 00 00 04 00 00 00     call 4
       4:   b7 00 00 00 00 00 00 00     r0 = 0
       5:   95 00 00 00 00 00 00 00     exit
```

`uname -a`:
Linux ubuntu1710 4.13.0-32-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 25 09:13:46 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

EDIT:

As an experiment, I tried loading a program similar to [the example program](http://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/716788/) described when `bpf_probe_read_str` was introduced as a helper function:

```
#define BUFSIZE 256

SEC("kprobe/sys_open")
void bpf_sys_open(struct pt_regs *ctx)
{
  char buf[BUFSIZE];
  bpf_probe_read(buf, sizeof(buf), (void *)ctx->di);
}
```

Which loads with no issues and gives the following assembly:

```
Disassembly of section kprobe/sys_open:
bpf_sys_open:
       0:   79 13 70 00 00 00 00 00     r3 = *(u64 *)(r1 + 112)
       1:   bf a1 00 00 00 00 00 00     r1 = r10
       2:   07 01 00 00 00 ff ff ff     r1 += -256
       3:   b7 02 00 00 00 01 00 00     r2 = 256
       4:   85 00 00 00 04 00 00 00     call 4
       5:   95 00 00 00 00 00 00 00     exit
```

So it seems that my `tty_write` program is passing the third register straight to the call to `bpf_probe_read` from when it was set after the kprobe was triggered; this may be the cause of the error I'm seeing, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've discovered yourself, the issue comes from the use of additional parameters to `kprobe__tty_write`. This works in [`ttysnoop`](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/tools/ttysnoop.py) because it uses bcc to compile and load BPF programs. **bcc actually rewrites the additional parameters** to the `ctx->xx` dereferences. You can see this with the following snippet:

```
from bcc import BPF
BPF(text="""
#include <linux/ptrace.h>
int kprobe__tty_write(struct pt_regs *ctx, struct file *file, const char __user *buf, size_t count) {
return 0;
}
""", debug=4)
```

Thanks to `debug=4`, we can see the rewrites when executing:

```
$ sudo python tmp.py
clang -cc1 -triple x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -emit-llvm-bc -emit-llvm-uselists -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name main.c -mrelocation-model static -mthread-model posix -fmath-errno -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -fuse-init-array -target-cpu x86-64 -momit-leaf-frame-pointer -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=gdb -coverage-notes-file /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-112-generic/main.gcno -nostdsysteminc -nobuiltininc -resource-dir lib/clang/5.0.1 -isystem /virtual/lib/clang/include -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -include /virtual/include/bcc/bpf.h -include /virtual/include/bcc/helpers.h -isystem /virtual/include -I /home/paul/bcc2 -I ./arch/x86/include -I arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I arch/x86/include/generated -I include -I ./arch/x86/include/uapi -I arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I ./include/uapi -I include/generated/uapi -D __KERNEL__ -D __HAVE_BUILTIN_BSWAP16__ -D __HAVE_BUILTIN_BSWAP32__ -D __HAVE_BUILTIN_BSWAP64__ -O2 -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-gnu-variable-sized-type-not-at-end -Wno-pragma-once-outside-header -Wno-address-of-packed-member -Wno-unknown-warning-option -Wno-unused-value -Wno-pointer-sign -fdebug-compilation-dir /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-112-generic -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 168 -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fdiagnostics-show-option -vectorize-loops -vectorize-slp -o main.bc -x c /virtual/main.c

#include <linux/ptrace.h>
__attribute__((section(".bpf.fn.kprobe__tty_write")))
int kprobe__tty_write(struct pt_regs *ctx) { struct file *file = ctx->di; const char __user *buf = ctx->si; size_t count = ctx->dx;
return 0;
}
```

---

In the same manner, bcc extract the function name from `kprobe__tty_write` and automagically attaches the BPF program to `tty_write`.

Comment: awesome, replaced the parameters with the correct context dereferences and it works beautifully :)